# Trying to remove number chars from the list, the characters will not remove and I do not know why

Tags: python

I wrote a program to intake the input from a file on the command line, it would then accept the inputs from the file as variables. A problem with the last 3 lines is that I cannot remove the characters '1' '2' and '3' from the list, as even when I wrote a function to do so it still does not work.

The output I  get is ['1 bb b\n', '2 a aab\n', '3 abbba bb\n']

the output I need is ['bb b', 'a aab', 'abbba bb']

Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
import sys
import re
#The input of the file needs to take the maximum size of the queue
#The input needs to choose a maximum number of states or depth
#The input needs to choose the set of dominoes

maxQueueSize = 0
maxStates = 0
outPutToken = 0;
numberOfDominoes = 0
dominoesFile = 0

def remove(list):
    pattern =r'[0-9]\n'
    list = [re.sub(pattern, '', i) for i in list]
    return list

def input_words(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    f = f.readlines()
    j = 0
    maxQueueSize = f[0]
    maxStates = f[1]
    outPutToken = bool(f[2])
    numberOfDominoes = f[3]
    dominoesFile = f[4: 7]
    for i in dominoesFile:
        dominesFile = remove(dominoesFile)
        #dominoesFile[j] = i.split()
        j+=1
    print(dominoesFile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_words(sys.argv[1])
#    print(maxQueueSize)
else :
    print("Please enter a file!")

class Domino:
    def __init__(self, top, bottom):
        self.top = ""
        self.bottom = ""
```

Comment: but Your regex is wrong, pattern `[0-9]\n` says, "find single occurrence of number character followed by newline character"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list = ['1 bb b\n', '2 a aab\n', '3 abbba bb\n']
list = [i.strip('0123456789\n \t') for i in list]
print(list)
```

In this, we provided the chars that we want to strip from the string.

output of the above:

```
['bb b', 'a aab', 'abbba bb']
```

Comment: It didn't work. But thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: @MATT_BOOTY, Do you mind elaborating ? did it throw an error ? or was the output incorrect ? I have added my output to the answer above and it matches what you requested in your question

Comment: Okay, you guys are getting a different output than I , and I have no idea why.

Comment: kindly share the output you are getting

Comment: Got it, it was fixed.

Comment: You do realize that the piece of code that I provided needs to be placed inside your `remove` function. And kindly make sure that your `remove` function is actually getting a list in input, it looks like it might be a string. Kindly debug once

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list = ['1 bb b\n', '2 a aab\n', '3 abbba bb\n']
>>> list = [i.strip()[2:] for i in list]
>>> list
['bb b', 'a aab', 'abbba bb']
```

Comment: Here is the output I got from your solution : [' b', 'ab', 'bba bb'].

Comment: so try `[i.strip() for i in list]`